# Android ToggleButton State reset after long time

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-togglebutton

I am creating an android app which contains a toggle button. I want to retain the state of the togglebutton. And it works great.If I left the togglebutton ON and comes back again to the app, the togglebutton retains its state, which is what I want. But the problem is that if i leave the app for so long, like more than 2 hours, the togglebutton state is not retained.ie, it sets to default state. Is there anyway to fix this? and yes I'm new to android :)

Heres my code

```
public static Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_page3);
onoff = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
onoff.setChecked(false);
onoff.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) 
{
  if (isChecked && !bundle.getBoolean("ToggleButtonState",false))
  {
     //do some tasks
   } else if(!isChecked) {
     //do some tasks
    }




  @Override
 public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    bundle.putBoolean("ToggleButtonState", onoff.isChecked());
}
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if(bundle.getBoolean("ToggleButtonState",false))
    {
        onoff.setChecked(true);

    }
 }
```

Comment: please show your code

Comment: i edited my question. heres the code

Comment: where is the bundle variable which is used in the onPause declared?

Comment: you didn't use any Shared Preference here?

Comment: sorry i didnt post the full code. but this is what i did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shared preferences can be used [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html#WriteSharedPreference) way. If your app is closed and opened again, your bundle object is recreated, reseted. If an application is not used for a while or the system needs more resources, your app can be killed, thats why your app is closed.

Code:

```
  private ToggleButton mTb;
    private SharedPreferences mSharedPref;
    private final String mPrefKey="toogle";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTb= (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton); // get ref for the toggle
        mSharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE); // init the sharedPreference
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // if the activty resumes set the toggle state
        boolean enabled = mSharedPref.getBoolean(mPrefKey,false); // if no value found then set it off, in this case this can happen first
        mTb.setChecked(enabled);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // if the activty closed etc.....
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPref.edit(); // get the pref editor
        editor.putBoolean(mPrefKey,mTb.isChecked()); // assign value to the key
        editor.commit();  // save the editors modifications
    }
```

Comment: so i should use shared preference?

Comment: Yes, you must use it.